# How to create intent / chooser to share external file?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm not quite sure what to ask or where to find this, so pardon if this sounds particularly dumb. I understand how to share data from my app using a custom provider.

What I am trying to do is create a chooser to share the currently playing music file. I get the filename from the `DATA` column in the `MediaStore` and then in my activity I have the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(song.filename));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Song File:"));
```

This correctly shows a list of applications to share with and choosing one populates the *name* of the file. However, the data does not get included. For example, if I share with Gmail then the attachment shows up by name *without a size* and then sending the email loses the attachment.

**NOTE**: Yes, sharing an external file is against current recommendations. Please respect that I know what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use [Uri.fromFile(new File(song.filename))](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile(java.io.File)) to get a good Uri to put into the intent.

Comment: What I have is not a `File` object but a `String filename`. For example, `"/mnt/sdcard/blahblah.mp3"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `file://` URIs for sharing. It requires the receiving application to have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Instead use [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) with `external-path` to allow the receiving app to access the file through your content provider without requiring special permissions.

To learn more, check out Ian Lake's video [Sharing Content (Android Development Patterns S2 Ep 6)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9TunRURWNU) and the associated artice [Sharing Content between Android apps](https://medium.com/@ianhlake/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b).

Comment: I suppose you didn't read the part of the question that said "I understand how to share data from my app using a custom provider."

Comment: My answer is less about the how, more about why using file:// URIs is wrong.

Comment: That belongs in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. It does answer the question. And I strongly believe it's a better approach than the one advocated by the other answer. Also, from the text it's not clear whether the OP doesn't want to use a content provider or just doesn't know how to deal with files not stored in app-private storage but external storage.

Comment: You can't say "it does answer the question" at the same time as "from the text it's not clear".  If there is lack of clarity, you can ask in a comment.  I found it particularly clear that the OP is asking specifically about the case where only a file path is known.  There are cases where this is necessary (for example, a file manager type app) so it's not fair to impose a Right Way of Doing Things without understanding the context.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that `EXTRA_STREAM` must contain a `content:` URI. The fact that many sending apps get this wrong is causing trouble for everyone else. There's no reason why a sending app can't wrap external files in a content provider. Assuming a receiving app that you know nothing about has permission to access external storage is wrong (in my opinion). It does answer the question "How to create intent / chooser to share external file?". Unless of course you insist "external file" equals `file:` URI.

Comment: The word "must" is never used in any documentation that I can find.  It's *recommended* to use a ContentProvider as show here (http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html), but at the end of the day, if the receiver needs a stream, they'll just use Uri.openInputStream, which handles file uris anyway. Or if the receiver actually wants a path to a file, the path is right there.  We simply don't know who the expected receivers are or if the sender actually wants the receiver to bring its own permissions anyway.  You should check with the OP before answering.

Comment: Thanks for the spirited discussion you two! I do understand content providers and wrote a custom one derived from the `FileProvider`. My question was *specifically* about external files, regardless of what current recommendations are, and Doug answered that succinctly. I have updated my question with a note on this.